# Does Phonegap support fetching data from webserver in defined interval?

Tags: cordova, intervals

We are going to develop an App with the Phonegap Framework, and we are wondering if it supports something like pulling data in an interval from our server and if the response has new data, notify the user. We havent started yet so we just would like to know before we start working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova does not natively support some type of polling like what you are looking for, however, it doesn't seem like it would be too difficult to write this in JavaScript. Now, if you want to poll your server while the application is not running / in the background, that might be more difficult and you will need to look into Cordova plugins to run stuff in the background.